# Read attributes of json external link with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

Hi I want to do a reverse geocodoing from longitude and lontitude google map api to do that I should add the LonLat to a link to get a JSON structure this the link of JSON file http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.0235202,-6.8317697&sensor=true 
 from this link I want to read the attribute

> formatted_address

this how I get the JSON file

> $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+loca.toString()+'&sensor=true',
>   function(data) {
>           alert(data.results.formatted_address[0]);
>        });          }

but it shows me this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

and thank you for helping me

Comment: is `loca` or `local`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from the api looks something like this:

```
{
  results: [{
    ...
    formatted_address: "39 Tirle Bank Way, Tewkesbury, Gloucestershire GL20 8ES, UK"
    ...
  },
  ...
  ],
  status: "OK"
}
```

You're trying to access `formatted_address` like an array with `[0]`, when it is actually a string. It's `results` that is an array. This should work for you if you only care about the first result:

```
$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+loca.toString()+'&sensor=true', function(data) { 
  if (data.status === 'OK') {
     alert(data.results[0].formatted_address); 
  }
  else {
    alert('Error! ' + data.status)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.0235202,-6.8317697&sensor=true', 
function(data) {  alert(data.results[0].formatted_address); });
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation please? Code-only answers don't tend to be as helpful.